# Grouping and capturing works for toy problem, not real world

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Toy problem:

```
$ echo "foo <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a> bar" | sed -E 's@.*<a href=/topic/[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>.*@\1@'
Null hypothesis
```

Real world (sed does not filter anything):

```
$ cat *html | grep '<a href="/topic' | sed -E 's@.*<a href=/topic/[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>.*@\1@'
                <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/approximation/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Approximation</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/estimation-methods/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Estimation methods</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/statistical-variance/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Statistical variance</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/identifiability/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Identifiability</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/preliminary-estimates/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Preliminary estimates</a>, 
                <a href="/topic/matrix-inversion/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Matrix inversion</a>
```

What change needs to made to get 'Null hypothesis'?

PS:

```
$ cat *html | grep -n10 '<a href="/topic' | sed -E 's@.*<a href=/topic/[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>.*@\1@'
538-
539-                
540-
541-
542-
543-    
544-        <div class="topics-list mtl">
545-            <p class="hide">You can always find the topics here!</p>
546-            <strong>Topics:</strong>
547-            
548:                <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a>, 
549-            
550:                <a href="/topic/approximation/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Approximation</a>, 
551-            
552:                <a href="/topic/estimation-methods/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Estimation methods</a>, 
553-            
554:                <a href="/topic/statistical-variance/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Statistical variance</a>, 
555-            
556:                <a href="/topic/identifiability/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Identifiability</a>, 
557-            
558:                <a href="/topic/preliminary-estimates/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Preliminary estimates</a>, 
559-            
560:                <a href="/topic/matrix-inversion/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Matrix inversion</a>
561-            
562-        </div>
563-
564-        <div class="mvl left">
565-            
566-
567-
568-
569-<div id="flag-description" aria-live="assertive">
570-    <a class="hover" data-qa="give-feedback" data-toggle="flag-reason" href="#" title="Give feedback on the topics for this item.">
```

ṔS2: the complete *html file: https://pastebin.com/RLnWXKWe

Comment: How could `href=/topic/` match `href="/topic/`. Double quotes can't be just inserted anywhere.

Comment: Because `echo "foo <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="` has a double-quoted string `foo <a href=`, an *unquoted* string `/topic/null-hypothesis/`, a second double-quoted string ` data-sc=`, and so on, meaning the quotes are not present when `sed` sees the text. I believe it would work otherwise in both cases with the appropriate changes.

Comment: This is what the toy thing should have been: `$ echo "foo <a href=\"/topic/null-hypothesis/\" data-sc=\"text link:topic link\">Null hypothesis</a> bar" | sed -E 's@.*<a href=\"/topic/[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>.*@\1@'
Null hypothesis` Actually, not necessary to escape the dq in the replacement.

Answer (score 0):

`cat *html | grep -oE '\"\/.*\/\"' | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}'`
This should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should try running your first command
just up to (but not including) the `|` — i.e., *just* the `echo` command.

```
$ echo "foo <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a> bar"
foo <a href=/topic/null-hypothesis/ data-sc=text link:topic link>Null hypothesis</a> bar
```

See anything wrong? 
Were you expecting `href=` and `data-sc=` to be followed
by ***quoted*** strings?

Your `echo` command is wrong. 
The `"` at the beginning doesn’t match the `"` at the end;
it matches the first one it finds:

```
$ echo "foo <a href="/topic/null-hypothesis/" data-sc="text link:topic link">Null hypothesis</a> bar"
       ↑▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲↑.......................↑▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲↑....................↑▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲▲↑
```

The characters with `▲` symbols under them are between quotes —
so you have successfully quoted the `<` and `>` characters,
which would have caused a mess it they weren’t quoted. 
The characters with `.` under them aren't quoted. 
And the quotes themselves aren’t quoted!

The simplest way to quote a quote is to use the other kind of quote —
i.e., change the first and last `"` to `'`.

Then fix your sed command to work with the *correct* toy data, like this:

> ```
> sed -E 's@.*<a href="/topic/[^>]*>([^<]*)</a>.*@\1@'
> ```
>
> Note the added `"` after the `href=`.

and you should be fine with the real data.

Comment: "You should try running your first command just up to (but not including) the | — i.e., just the echo command." this answer comes after [this comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/527779/grouping-and-capturing-works-for-toy-problem-not-real-world/527801#comment976559_527779), so I'm not sure it's still relevant.